# Moodle, Block Activities set results

Tags: php, sql, moodle

I have resources named

- `XYZ.pdf`,
- `LMO.pdf`,
- `Sample.pdf`

in week 1 of `CourseGR1101` and resources named

- `ABC.pdf`,
- `test.PDF`
- and `Sample.PDF`

in week 2 of `CourseGR1101`.

Is there a way to make the `"activities block"` show the resources that names are similar to (like/where query) sampl%, without showing `ABC.pdf`, `XYZ.PDF`, `LMO.PDF`, ...?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a HTML block and manually link to each activity. Alternatively it would be fairly straightforward for a developer with Moodle experience to create a custom block to do what you want.

The built in activities block does not support what you are wanting.

Comment: I would like the activities be automatically grouped in each course based on their names on a sidebar block